# Qt Installer Framework: How to uninstall previous versions?

Tags: windows, qt, registry, uninstallation, qt-installer

When I create the (offline) installer, how can I use the installer script to **find** and **uninstall** any previous versions of the software? Knowing that the user could have installed them anywhere in the past?

Answer (score 2):

If the previous installers didn't register the location somewhere in the registry, or in a "signature" file in the installation folder, then generally there's no way to uninstall without the risk of deleting a version that the user maintains themselves and doesn't intend to remove.

But generally, you'll have to search for uninstallers (if such exist), or installation manifests (msi or os x), and invoke the uninstaller or platform installation system to do the uninstall. You'd have to specify exactly what sort of a system was used for installation, and what "tracks" it left behind, to get more specific advice (i.e. code examples).